# Fixed Bootstrap Nav bar overridden by page content

Tags: bootstrap-4, navigation

I am using the nav bar example from here [nav bar example](https://codepen.io/albizan/pen/mMWdWZ):

Issue I am having is when I scroll down the page the nav bar, which is fixed,  it is overridden by the content below it.

This is the nav bar:

```
<!-- Navigation if fluidic defult-->
<nav class="nav">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="#">Your Logo</a>
        </div>
        <div id="mainListDiv" class="main_list">
            <ul class="navlinks">
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <span class="navTrigger">
            <i></i>
            <i></i>
            <i></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</nav>

<section class="home">
</section>
<div style="height: 1000px">
    <!-- just to make scrolling effect possible -->
```

Now my own content begins here, it consists of a bootstrap carousel and cards wrapped in a bootstrap container:

```
!--Main contnet wraped in container Bootstrap grid system-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!--Take 3 columsn width for our left most list menu-->
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <h1 class="my-4">Shop Name</h1>
            <div class="list-group ">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item ">Category 1</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item ">Category 1</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item ">Category 1</a>
            </div>

        </div>

        <!--Main body - Botstrap Carousle-->
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide carousel-fade my-4 " data-ride="carousel">
```

I have not included all the code as its quite length.

This is an image of the nav bar been overridden by the content below it as you scroll down the page:

[image: Fixed nav bar overridden as we scroll down the page]

So my question what could cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add other classes such as `fixed-top` in order to get it fixed and over the content. Try:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top">
  […]
</nav>
```

Consider that using a `nav` element here is wrong. You should try something like:

```
<header class="navbar fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" >Your Logo</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <nav class="navbar-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

My example is far from being complete, but you can see more examples here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navbar/. Your element must have a `fixed-*` class to get a `z-index` higher than the contents below or it could be overridden like so. If you plan to add two or more elements with position `absolute` or `fixed`, then you should set a `z-index` for each accordingly.